# How to tell what time I sent a text?

Tags: ichat, chat

Is there any way to find out when exactly an un-timestamped chat was sent?

My friend Max swears I didn't promptly inform him of my whereabouts this past weekend. I remember the exchange differently.

A  screenshot:

[image]

Is there any way to know for sure?

(I am using iOS 6 on an iPhone 4S.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this:

Delete the texts above the un-timestamped text until the relevant message is assigned a timestamp. In this case you will just have to delete one message.

Comment: If the text you're curious about is the most recent in the conversation, go back to your list of texts and it'll show the exact minute. I realize that's not the case here but it can be handy.